# Add an Object in the namespace with a "AddIn" reference

Tags: node-opcua

I am using node-opcua to create an OPC UA Server. The nodeset of the companion specification that i am working with dictates an "AddIn" Reference.

Is it possible to add an Object to the namespace that is referenced as hasAddIn by it's parent object?

There is no property like "addInOf" within **AddObjectTypeOptions** such as "componentOf".

To add components to an object I use

```
const _Identification = namespace.addObject({
     componentOf: myMachine,
     browseName: "Identification",
     typeDefinition: baseObjectType.getChildByName('FolderType').getChildByName('FunctionalGroupType').getChildByName('MachineIdentificationType').getChildByName('MachineToolIdentificationType')
});
```

Alternatively I thought of creating the object as a component first and change the reference afterwards but I dind't find a suitable method.

Answer (score 3):

To add the `HasAddIn` reference between nodes, you can make use of the `references` property of the `AddBaseNodeOptions` interface. It is of type `AddReferenceOpts`.

To add `AddIn` reference to object,

```
const _Identification = namespace.addObject({
    browseName: "Identification",
    references: [{
        referenceType: "HasAddIn",
        nodeId: <provide the nodeId of the AddIn here>
    }]
});
```

Hope this answers your question.